# Shorewall - Allow Client to Ping Internet but Not Use the Browser or Port 80

Tags: networking, server, firewall

My network address is `192.168.5.0`. My host machine is `192.168.5.1` and my client machine is `192.168.5.2`. How will I enable my client to ping the internet through the terminal but restrict it from using port `80` or the browser? Below is my `/etc/shorewall/policy` file :

```
SOURCE    DEST    POLICY    LOGLEVEL   RATE    CONNLIMIT

loc       net     ACCEPT

net       all     DROP      info
```

`/etc/shorewall/rules` file:

```
DROP    loc    fw    tcp   80
```

`/etc/shorewall/interfaces` file :

```
net   eth0
loc   eth1
```

Host Interfaces:

```
eth0 - Connection to the internet
eth1 - Local Network Connection
```

Please tell me, if I still have to provide more details. Using the configuration above, my client is unable to ping any internet website and at the same time cant access any site from the browser.

Answer (score 3):

On **rules**, when you use:

```
DROP    loc    fw    tcp   80
```

Your're saying: disallow **local network zone** (loc) from access port TCP/80 on zone fw. But your conf shows no zone called **fw** (probably you meant $FW, but that would represent the firewall machine itself). You could try something like this:

```
Ping(ACCEPT)    loc    net
HTTP(DROP)      loc    net
HTTPS(DROP)     loc    net
```

AFAICR, shorewall adds a DROP ALL rule at the end of each chain*, so the two rules for dropping HTTP and HTTPS could be removed (because everything that isn't explicitly allowed is blocked by the final DROP ALL rule).

*This behaviour is defined at the **policy** file.